# ag-grid - Angular Data Grid: Group Cell Renderer

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Is the resource [Angular Data Grid: Group Cell Renderer](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/group-cell-renderer/#example-group-renderer), free for commercial use?
I ask because in the documentation it is explicit that for the refusal to work it is necessary to import the package from the **ag-grid enterprise**, and if I remove it does not work.

```
// app/app.component.ts (QUESTION IMPORT)
import  'ag-grid-enterprise';
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is required to import **ag-grid enterprise** to use Angular Data Grid: Group Cell Renderer